# numpy.array2string not detecting native types

Tags: python, numpy, serialization

I'm trying to convert pandas dataframes to query strings for an SQL Server.  To do this I have serialize python `bool` types as `0` or `1`. 
I've been using:

```
>>>import pandas as pd
>>>import numpy as np
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame([[0,"one",False] for l in range(5)], columns=["a","b","c"])
>>> strOut = [np.array2string(l, separator=',', formatter={'bool':lambda x: int(x)}) for l in df1.values]
>>> strOut
["[0,'one',False]", "[0,'one',False]", "[0,'one',False]", "[0,'one',False]", "[0,'one',False]"]
```

however you can see that the numpy.array2string formatter isn't detecting the native `bool` type in the above.  If I look at the example in the docs

```
>>> x  = np.arange(3)
>>> np.array2string(x, formatter={'int':lambda x: hex(x)})
'[0x0L 0x1L 0x2L]'
```

you can see it works.  I've detected the type of the values in `x` from the example to see that they are actually `dtype(int32)` not `int`.   So i tried to do the same in my code and no cigar again.

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame([[0,"one",False] for l in range(5)], columns=["a","b","c"])
>>> strOut = [np.array2string(l, separator=',', formatter={'int':lambda x: hex(x)}) for l in df1.values]
>>> strOut
["[0,'one',False]", "[0,'one',False]", "[0,'one',False]", "[0,'one',False]", "[0,'one',False]"]
```

no change.  Is there a way to make `numpy.array2string` work with native types?   Or.. alternativly is there a better way to serialize query strings from dataframes.  Note however, that brining in outside libraries is not an option here.  I know I could bring in sqlalchemy or something like that but for the sake of this question we're doing the work ourselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `array2string` not handling booleans.  The documentation clearly states that `bool` is a supported type for the `formatter` dictionary.  The issue is entirely with the datatype of your array, when you call `df1.values`.

You are  working on an array of dtype `object`, so `array2string` is missing your booleans.  You can see this behavior when you add in a formatter for dtype `object` (note *every* value is being picked up by the formatter):

```
s = np.array2string(df1.values, separator=',', formatter={'object': lambda x: 'BAD'})
print(s)
```

```
[[BAD,BAD,BAD],
 [BAD,BAD,BAD],
 [BAD,BAD,BAD],
 [BAD,BAD,BAD],
 [BAD,BAD,BAD]]
```

I personally would handle the conversion *before* you attempt to use `array2string`, so that you don't have to make use of the `formatter` on a mixed type array, or possibly use the function on individual series' only.